# wrap text around custom fields array

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I'm using this code here to grab all my custom fields from a post for use in an gallery array.

http://www.kevinleary.net/get-all-custom-fields-attached-post-page-post-type/

**function:**

```
//  Get all custom fields attached to a page
if ( !function_exists('base_get_all_custom_fields') ) {
function base_get_all_custom_fields()
{
    global $post;
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $hidden_field = '_';
    foreach( $custom_fields as $key => $value ){
        if( !empty($value) ) {
            $pos = strpos($key, $hidden_field);
            if( $pos !== false && $pos == 0 ) {
                unset($custom_fields[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $custom_fields;
}
}
```

**single.php:**

```
// Get all custom fields attached to this post and store them in an array
$custom_fields = base_get_all_custom_fields();
if( !empty($custom_fields) ) {
print_r($custom_fields);
}
```

It works, but outputs text like this around the custom post `Array ( [photo1] => Array ( [0] =>`

Is there a way to customise what you wrap before & after a custom field output, and remove the array text?

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
{image : 'http://website.com/slides/photo1.jpg'}, 
{image : 'http://website.com/slides/photo2.jpg'},  
{image : 'http://website.com/slides/photo3.jpg'},
```

so I need to wrap `{image : '` before and `'},` after the link.

I can sort of do it with single queries but the array system would be better

```
{image : '<?php echo $custom_fields['photo1'][0]; ?>'},
{image : '<?php echo $custom_fields['photo2'][0]; ?>'},
{image : '<?php echo $custom_fields['photo3'][0]; ?>'},
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if( !empty($custom_fields) ) {
    $output = '';
    foreach( $custom_fields as $key => $value ){
        foreach( $value as $val ){
            $output .= "{".$key." : '".$val."'},";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds... :)

Comment: hi - that doesn't seem to work? just getting a blank page. Do i need to amend something?

Comment: Should this be added to my existing code or replace it?

Comment: hi - could you let me know where that code goes -is it the functions or tempalte file?

Comment: this would replace the `if( !empty($custom_fields) ) { }` section in your single.php file

Comment: thanks a million milo for the clear explanation - that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you're asking, but as far as i understood you're trying to get some *"stuff"* before/after every custom field value?

**EDIT:** Has to be placed in your functions.php file

```
function wpse20348_custom_field_output( $echo = false )
{
    $custom_fields = base_get_all_custom_fields();

    if ( empty( $custom_fields ) ) 
        return;

    $output = '';

    $prefix = '{image : ';
    $suffix = '}';

    foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $field )
    {
        $output .= $prefix.$field.$suffix;
    }

    if ( $echo === false )
        return $output;

    return print $output;
}
// Call it like this in your theme:
wpse20348_custom_field_output( true );

// or save it for further processing:
$wpse_custom_fields = wpse20348_custom_field_output();
```

It might be that you need to change `$prefix` to your needs. It might also be that you need to append `[0]` to `$field` inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: do I wrap this in php tags in template? just gives me errors.`<?php  wpse20348_custom_field_output( true ); ?>`

Comment: Yes, you need to wrap everything that's not html in php tags. Plus: See update.

Comment: Btw: `print_r( $var );` and `var_dump( $var );` are just there to show you what's inside a variable, array or object. They are meant for debugging, not production. To output something use `print` or `echo` and read a little about php basics on the [official resource](http://php.net).

Comment: Hmm I have this in functions     `function wpse20348_custom_field_output( $echo = false )
{
    $custom_fields = base_get_all_custom_fields();

    if ( empty( $custom_fields ) ) 
        return;

    $output = '';

    $prefix = '{image : ';
    $suffix = '}';

    foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $field )
    {
        $output .= $prefix.$field.$suffix;
    }

    if ( $echo === false )
        return $output;

    return print $output;
}
}' and this    `<?php wpse20348_custom_field_output( true ); ?>` in single.php but I'm just getting blank.

Comment: As i said: Your problem is the basic understanding of php and html in one template. Please take yourself an hour or two and read a little in the official docs. It will save you a lot of time trying to get around really basic stuff.

Comment: ok - but if your answer is the solution and it doesn't work when I put it where you say surely there must be something wrong? Is there other code I need?  I've placed it as you posted in functions.php and the other code in single.php in a base install of wordpress.

Comment: And that's exactly your problem: You (so far) don't know how to handle html & php in a file. Your problem are (with a 99% possibility) the tags. **Please** read the manual for an hour, then give it a try, else come back and ask again.

Comment: what do you mean 'don't know how to handle html & php in a file'?  I've removed all my original code from function.php and single.php and replaced them with the suggestions in your reply. Should I also be including the code in the reply from Milo?

Comment: If you got a blank screen, I'd guess you forgot to open or close html tags in the right place. That's what I meant. You can edit your Q with a link to a pastebin to your functions.php and anotherone with your single.php code. But here the journey ends for me. Learn some basic php and html. Else you'll loose much more time than you'd invest into learning the stuff (approximately 2 hours). So (for the last time): **PLEASE READ THE MANUAL**!